# Expanding MS-Access graph of 1 aggregate sum value to up to 5 aggregate sum values selected by a user

Tags: sql, ms-access, graph, aggregate

I have a working form which creates an access graph report based on a value selected by the user in an access form - the SQL to create the graph data is:

```
SELECT AccountBalances.RecDate, 
       Sum(AccountBalances.[End Balance]) AS [SumOfEnd Balance], 
       CombinedFSLineItems.[CFS LineDescription]    
FROM (CombinedFSLineItems 
INNER JOIN AccountNumbers  
     ON CombinedFSLineItems.[CFS LineItem] = AccountNumbers.[CFS LineItem]) 
INNER JOIN AccountBalances 
     ON AccountNumbers.[Account#] = AccountBalances.[Account#]
GROUP BY AccountBalances.RecDate, 
         CombinedFSLineItems.[CFS LineDescription], 
         AccountBalances.StoreID, CombinedFSLineItems.[CFS LineItem]
HAVING (((AccountBalances.RecDate) >= [TempVars]![varStartDate] 
  AND (AccountBalances.RecDate) <= [TempVars]![varDate]) 
  AND ((AccountBalances.StoreID) = [TempVars]![varStoreID]) 
  AND ((CombinedFSLineItems.[CFS LineItem]) = [TempVars]![varCFSLineItem]));
```

A little background would help here.  There are 3 tables used by the query

1. **CombinedFSLineItems**: A report Definition Table which defines the line Items of a financial report. Relevant fields for this discussion are `[CFS LineItem]` and `[CFS LineDescription]`.
2. **AccountNumbers**: A table that lists all the account numbers and attributes such as which CFS Report LineItem it is part of and which Store it is associated with.  Relevant fields for this discussion are `[StoreID]`, `[CFS LineItem]` and `[Account#]`.
3. **AccountBalances**: A table that contains the monthly data for every account for each store.  The relevant fields for this discussion are `[StoreID]`, `[Account#]`, and `[End Balance]`.

The user selects the store and `CFS LineItem` to be graphed on a Form which sets the TempVars: `[varStoreID]` and `[varCFSLineItem]`.  The query is the source of the graph report data.  It sums all the accounts that comprise that CFS Line Item for that store and then the graph presents the data over the months available in the data.

Now I'd like to allow the user to select up to 5 Line Items and create a graph of all 5.  Any and all ideas on best way to do that would be appreciated.

Thanks!
Mike

EDIT 4/13/20 1:30pm

---

Sample Data...

1. Combined FSLineItems Tbl

   ```
   CFS, LineItemCFS, Line, Description  
   1, Actual Cash  
   2, Contracts in Transit         
   7, Customer COD  
   19, Fixed Assets  
   …
   ```
2. AccountNumbers Tbl

   ```
   StoreID, Account#, CFS LineItem  
   1, 101, 1  
   1, 102, 1 
   1, 103, 1  
   1, 104, 2  
   1, 105, 2  
   1, 106, 19  
   1, 107, 19  
   1, 108, 19  
   2, 101, 7  
   2, 102, 1  
   2, 106, 1
   ```
3. AccountBalances Tbl

   ```
   Account#, StoreID, End Balance, RecDate  
   101, 1, 10,000.00, 1/1/2020  
   101, 1, 15,000.00, 2/1/2020    
   101, 1, 5,000.00, 12/1/2019  
   102, 1, 1,000.00, 1/1/2020  
   102, 1, 500.00, 2/1/2020  
   102, 1, 1,000.00, 12/1/2019  
   104, 1, 2,500.00, 1/1/2020  
   104, 1, 3,000.00, 2/1/2020  
   104, 1, 1,500.00, 12/1/2019  
   105, 1, 1,000.00, 1/1/2020  
   105, 1, 1,500.00, 2/1/2020  
   105, 1, 1,000.00, 12/1/2019  
   104, 2, 3,000.00, 1/1/2020  
   104, 2, 4,000.00, 12/1/2019  
   104, 2, 5,000.00, 2/1/2020  
   105, 2, 1,500.00, 1/1/2020  

   ***
   ```

Using the above sample data, if the user selected store 1 and CFS LineItem 1 and CFS LineItem 2 I would want a graph with 2 Lines:

- Line 1 being CFS LineItem1 having the values of 6,000 11,000 15,500 for Dec Jan Feb
- Line 2 being CFS LineItem2 having the values of 2,500 3,500 4,500 for Dec Jan Feb

I'd also like to name the Lines in the graph based on the Combined FS LineItems Table field `[CFS LineDescription]`.

Ideally, I could create a SQL statement that could be used as the source data for an Access Report Graph.  If VBA code or macros are required that's fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Do you want added, new columns or extended new rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [MS Access charts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-chart-on-a-form-or-report-1a463106-65d0-4dbb-9d66-4ecb737ea7f7) usually follow Excel pivot table data model, you would simply need a *longer* query with same structure (i.e., more rows) which can be handled with an `IN` clause of more *TempVars*.

Consider following adjustment with *varCFSLineItem1-5* variables. Also, below query converts `HAVING` to `WHERE` and uses table aliases for readability and repeats same columns in `GROUP BY` in `SELECT`. Be sure to adjust graph to needed fields:

```
SELECT b.RecDate, 
       b.StoreID, 
       c.[CFS LineDescription],
       c.[CFS LineItem],
       SUM(b.[End Balance]) AS [SumOfEnd Balance]  

FROM (CombinedFSLineItems c
INNER JOIN AccountNumbers a
     ON c.[CFS LineItem] = a.[CFS LineItem]) 
INNER JOIN AccountBalances b
     ON a.[Account#] = b.[Account#]

WHERE (b.RecDate >= [TempVars]![varStartDate] 
  AND  b.RecDate <= [TempVars]![varDate]) 
  AND (b.StoreID = [TempVars]![varStoreID]) 

  AND (c.[CFS LineItem] IN ([TempVars]![varCFSLineItem1],
                            [TempVars]![varCFSLineItem2],
                            [TempVars]![varCFSLineItem3],
                            [TempVars]![varCFSLineItem4],
                            [TempVars]![varCFSLineItem5])
      )

GROUP BY b.RecDate, 
         c.[CFS LineDescription], 
         b.StoreID, 
         c.[CFS LineItem]
```

Comment: Parfait - Thank you for that suggestion - worked great.  All I then needed to do was a CrossTab query on it to get the data in columnar format so Access could graph it.